# What is the automation support for theories other than HOL in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

According to my scan of the Isabelle files, the Sledgehammer tool is only available for Isabelle/HOL. I'm curious about the automation of other theories in Isabelle. For instance:

- Isabelle/ZF
- Isabelle/FOL

Do they support:

- automatic provers
- SMT solvers
- specialized decision procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isabelle/ZF does not support SMT solvers or specialized decision procedures. As for "automatic provers" I am not sure if that counts but the method `auto` is quite capable. In some cases it allows to prove a theorem just referencing the premises and a list of several theorems, see for example theorem [`bij_base_open_homeo`](https://isarmathlib.org/Topology_ZF_2.html#a_bij_base_open_homeo) in IsarMathLib.

Comment: there is actually metis for FOL

Comment: at least according to metis_tactic.ML

Comment: There is a manual specifying automation for different object logics: https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2018/dist/Isabelle2018/doc/logics.pdf